# The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: .net, json, object

I am using .NET Framework 4.5 and I'm having this issue.
`The type or namespace 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System'`

I tried to `Install-Package System.Json -Version 4.0.20126.16343` but I had this issue afterwards.

```
The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Source: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json

Any ideas would be really appreciated!

Comment: What does this mean do you think? "The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore."

Comment: I understand. So if I don't use this then, what's your solution on this?

Regards,Pavlos

Comment: What kind of application are you creating?

Comment: A really simple console application to convert a custom xml to json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That package is discontinued and shouldn't be used any more.

If you have a console application, I could recommend two options:

- [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Not a part of the .NET Framework itself, but much faster than Microsofts implementation;
- Microsofts implementation of the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Both are capable of reading and writing JSON. I find the JSON.NET library easier to use and more feature complete.

Comment: I already use this, but as I described above, the error that I have is that "The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namepsace 'System' "

Comment: `System.Json` isn't the namespace of either of those. It is either `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

Comment: *That package is discontinued* - I think it's worth adding *for .NET Framework 4.5*, which the OP referred to? today it's built in into .NET Core 3.0 and later versions, and  can be installed as a NuGet package for .NET Standard 2.0 and later versions, .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, and .NET Core 2.0, 2.1, and 2.2 ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview)).

Answer (score 2):

`using Newtonsoft.Json;` should get the job done.

Now you can use:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
```

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer