# Is using the system.text.json no longer possible for serializing / deserialiing in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

As described in the official microsoft docs which has been Updated in September of 2019 it says that using `system.text.json` for serializing or deserializing can be done.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

However when I tried that in a program I was working on , I kept getting the error `using system.text.json does not exist`

This made me stumble upon this Stack Overflow Question

[The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863514/the-type-or-namespace-name-json-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-are)

In which as shown above says that the

> package is discontinued and shouldn't be used any more.

Is there any update on this ? or Is there any way I can work around with `system.text.json`

Comment: Are you targeting .Net Core 3.0+? - [System.Text.Json Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: Negative.. Is this namespace only supported  in  that ?

Comment: Have you looked into using Newtonsoft assym?I Find it much simpler and easier to use

Comment: you are not required to have .Net Core 3.0+... even though System.Text.Json is built in to 3.0, you can still install it.. see how to get it section... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview

Comment: Thank for the comment .. Actually one of the main reason why I sort of need to work around the system.text.json is because I need to use this in a c sharp script ( CSX ) and using newton soft is not an option because I do not want to use an external dll (due  to it not suiting the natre in which I am using this script )

Comment: Is there any way to use this json deserializer without installing anything ?

Comment: @Jawad ^ incase you missed the above comment

Comment: [`System.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json) is something completely different than [`System.Text.Json`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/).  While `System.Json` has been deprecated, `System.Text.Json` is Microsoft's new JSON serializer and should be supported moving forward.  It's built into .net core 3.0 and above and can be added to .NETFramework 4.6.1 and above.

Answer (score 39):

You just have to install the `System.Text.Json` NuGet package.

1. In Solution Explorer select your solution (at the root of the tree) and click with right mouse button.
2. In the contextual menu choose `Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions...`
3. In the window that will appear, click on `Browse` on the top.
4. In the search textbox type `System.Text.Json`
5. Select the package, then on the right select all the project of your solution for which you want the package to be installed, and then click on the `Install` button.

Comment: Anybody knows what to do in case Project > Manage Nuget Packages shows System.Text.Json as installed but visual studio still complains The type or namespace name Json does not exist in namespace System.Text... ? (Version System.Text.Json : 4.7.2 , Visual studio : 16.6.2, NuGetPackage Manager: 5.6.0 , Visual Studio: 16.6.2 , Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03752)

Comment: @Rose, hard to tell without seeing. I'm not promising anything, but if you can share a dummy .sln just having that issue i may take a look.

Comment: I found my solution. In my case, this is a Unity project, so I had to add the dll files into the Assets/plugins folder as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084186/json-net-in-unity-throwing-the-type-or-namespace-newtonsoft-could-not-be-foun

Comment: "293 million downloads"  So say that taking this out of C# is annoying is an understatement!  So glad the nuget package exists...

Comment: Why did they take it out?

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the corresponding **`System.Text.Json`** reference through References.

1. Right click on **References** in Solution explorer.
2. Once Reference Manager opens , go to Assemblies section . Scroll through all the assemblies and look out for `System.Text.Json` and then check this assembly.
3. Try again to add the namespace.

Though this assembly automatically comes along with all latest versions of Visual Studio, but in case you are not able to find the aforementioned assembly , then you may have to first install the corresponding Nuget package and then follow the above steps for adding the reference.